# Kotlin how to add data class return from when into list

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class Worker, I want to create a new Worker data and add into the list when meeting some condition.

Here is how I create the new Worker,

```html
var workerList = arrayListOf<Worker>()

when(hirePosition){
  android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
  ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
}
```

I know can use the workerList.add() method to add the data into the list, but I don't know how to make it when return from when condition.

Apologies as I'm fresh and not sure is this the correct way to code for this scenario, seek for any suggestion and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exhaustive `when` must have an `else` branch

```
when(hirePosition){
  android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
  ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
  else -> null
}?.let { workerList.add(it) }
```

Comment: the 'let' is the keys, I can access the particular worker() inside the let {}, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely understand what you meant, but you can return from when like this:

```
val worker: Worker = when(hirePosition) {
  android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
  ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
}

workerList.add(worker)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) if `when` is used as an **expression**, the value of the satisfied branch becomes the value of the overall expression

So there are possible variants:

```
var workerList = mutableListOf<Worker>()

val newWorker = when(hirePosition){
    android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
    ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
} 
workerList += newWorker
```

or

```
workerList += when(hirePosition){
    android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
    ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
}
```

or even

```
val workerList = listOf<Worker>(
    when(hirePosition){
        android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
        ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
    } 
)
```

Choose the best appropriate for your case/codestyle. For example the last variant is good for immutable list initialization (you should always prefer immutable versus mutable one)

Answer (score 1):

`when` is an expression, it returns the result of whichever branch it evaluates - so you can assign that result to something, like `val worker = when...`, or you can return it like `return when ...`, or you can chain a function call onto it, like `when {...}.hire()`...

Kotlin has a bunch of [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#scope-functions) like `let` which run on a thing and let you do stuff with it - there are a bunch and they differ mostly on how you access the object inside the function (do you run something *on* it or do something *with* it - receiver vs variable basically) and whether they return the result of that function, or the thing that was originally passed in, or nothing at all

Anyhow point is most of them will work for what you're doing, running an operation on your result and that's it. You can even use a function reference - `when {...}.run(workerList::add)` but that's a matter of taste (I like it a lot when it fits!)

---

But a more Kotlin-y approach is to generate the list all at once, so it's a fixed immutable list instead. It depends on your use case - if you need to keep adding people at different times, that's probably not going to work. But just in case, here's one way you could generate your list:

```
fun getWorker(position: HirePosition) = when(position) {
      android -> Worker(nameA, ageA)
      ios ->  Worker(nameB, ageB)
}

// or map(::getWorker)
val workerList = availablePositions.map { getWorker(it) }
```

That's the general "transform a collection of things into a list of other things* approach. You could stick the `when` block in the `map` lambda, but I think it's more readable to break it out into its own function and give it a readable name.

There are other things you can do, like `buildList` (takes a mutable list and lets you add to it - so you could run it on a bunch of `HirePosition`s to add more to your `workerList`) but uh that's enough for now eh